# Return difference from two numbers representing day of the week

Tags: ruby

I have an object with two attributes, each with a weekday saved as a numeric value `0-6`. E.g.

```
.attribute_one
=> 5

.attribute_two
=> 0
```

How would I construct an algorithm returning the day difference?

The second day attribute always occurs last, so the difference can not be minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
def difference
  diff = attribute_two - attribute_one
  diff < 0 ? diff + 7 : diff
end
```